# Pointer's elements saved as gibberish

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, c++14

I have written code that attempts to solve the Missionary and Cannibal's problem and have implemented `Node` to save information in `Node::arr` and `Node::parent`. These, when returned by the function `bfs`, will give the states in the shortest path.

When `bfs` returns, it has the right number of `parents`. However, when I inspected `Node last` in the Visual Studio debugger, I noticed that its `parents.arr` contain garbage i.e. `arr[0]=-858993460`. but `Node last` has the correct `arr` (the final state of the problem `{0,0,1,3,3,0}`). How is this information lost?

**node.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <array>
class Node {
public:
    std::array<int, 6> arr;
    Node *parent;
    Node(std::array<int, 6> arr, Node *parent = NULL);
    Node();
};
```

**node.cpp**

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(std::array<int, 6> arr, Node *parent) : arr(arr), parent(parent) {};
Node::Node(): parent(NULL) {};
```

**main.cpp**

```
void applyMoves(queue<Node> &q, Node current_node, array<int, 3> moves) {
  array<int, 6> arr = current_node.arr;
    array<int, 3> left, right;
    // apply valid moves to arr
    // copy the arr to left and right and check if the move applied are valid
    // if valid and no duplicates in the queue do proceed to the next lines below
    Node n = Node(arr, &current_node);
    q.push(n);

}

Node bfs(queue<Node> &q, array<array<int, 3>, 5> moves) {
    while (!q.empty()) {
        Node current = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (achievedGoal(current.arr) == 1) {
            return current;
        }
        for (const auto& move : moves) {
            applyMoves(q, current, move);
        }
    }
    Node n;
    return n;
}

int main() {
    array<int, 6> init_state{ 3,3,1,0,0,0 };
    array<array<int, 3>, 5> moves{ { {1,0,1}, {0,1,1}, {1,1,1}, {2,0,1}, {0,2,1} } };
    Node n = Node(init_state);
    queue<Node> q;
    q.push(n);
    Node last = bfs(q, moves);
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Your default `Node` constructor does not initialize `parent` (may be unrelated to the problem you are having).

Comment: Also, `applyMoves` takes `current_node` by value and then you use the address of that.

Comment: @crashmstr I changed `applyMoves` to take in `Node &current_node` and called like this `applyMoves(q, current, move);` However, when I inspect `Node last` there seem to be an un-ending 'levels' of where a `parent` points to a `parent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in

```
void applyMoves(queue<Node> &q, Node current_node, array<int, 3> moves) {
  array<int, 6> arr = current_node.arr;
    array<int, 3> left, right;
    // apply valid moves to arr
    // copy the arr to left and right and check if the move applied are valid
    // if valid and no duplicates in the queue do line 31 and 32
    Node n = Node(arr, &current_node);
    q.push(n);

}
```

Here `current_node` is a copy and you are storing the address of it.  When the function ends that copy is destroyed and now you have a dangling pointer.  You should be able to fix it by taking `current_node` by reference.

Edit:

You also have this same behavior in

```
Node bfs(queue<Node> &q, array<array<int, 3>, 5> moves) {
    while (!q.empty()) {
        Node current = q.front();
        q.pop();

        if (achievedGoal(current.arr) == 1) {
            return current;
        }
        for (const auto& move : moves) {
            applyMoves(q, current, move);
        }
    }
    Node n;
    return n;
}
```

Here you create `current` which is a local automatic object and you copy the front of the queue into it and then you get `pop()` the front out of the queue.  So when you use this node for the parent everything is fine until you move to the next iteration of the while loop.  Once you do that `current` is destroyed which means everything that points to it is now dangling.  Then the loop starts back up and a new `current` is created.  If this object is created in the sample place which I think it is then all of the nodes you have made have their parent node now pointing to this new node.

They way you are currently doing this is not going to work.  I am not quite sure how you should change it to get the correct behavior.

Comment: I changed `applyMoves` to take in `Node &current_node` and called like this `applyMoves(q, current, move);` However, when I inspect `Node last` there seem to be an un-ending 'levels' of where a parent points to a parent.

Comment: @user2348707 I have updated my answer.  Not quite sure how to fix the issue as the algo seams broken.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I have a better understanding of the problem. I quickly prototyped this in python and tried my hands dirty on C++ and they both behave very differently even though the code is almost identical. I will have to try another way to get the correct behavior.

Comment: @user2348707 No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't (yet) comment on posts made by others, I will build upon the previous answer with my own answer. Yes, the following function:

```
void applyMoves(queue<Node> &q, Node current_node, array<int, 3> moves) {
  array<int, 6> arr = current_node.arr;
    array<int, 3> left, right;
    // apply valid moves to arr
    // copy the arr to left and right and check if the move applied are valid
    // if valid and no duplicates in the queue do line 31 and 32
    Node n = Node(arr, &current_node);
    q.push(n);

}
```

Needs to take the current_node by reference, since, otherwise, you are storing a address to a local variable, which will be destroyed after the execution goes out of function scope.

But, not only that, but here:

```
    Node current = q.front();
    q.pop();
```

You are making a copy of the first element in the queue, and saving it to a local variable, and when you pass it into the function described above (even if it is done by reference), you are still running into the same problem, since you are storing the address of the local variable (local variable of different function, but still - the same problem). And, based on the logic posted, is not clear for me, what the correct solution would be, but at least you have "why?" answered.

Edit: Apparently the original poster beat me to an answer with his edit.

Comment: Thanks! A "why" answered is better than nothing. I have learned something at least.